# How to retrieve records created today in Data Extension using AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, datetime, format

In my data extension dynamically records will created every day. Here i want know how many records will created every day. I am unable to fetch the today date values in lookuprows for equal to Createddate field.

In my DE Createddate field value is Monday, "January 04, 2021 11:16 AM"
when i am print the Createddate field value will be like this  "1/4/2021 11:16:47 AM"

I also tried Createddate field static value, did not work on lookuprows. I have tried multiple ways like below. How can i achieve my requirement.

```
%%[
VAR @Today, @rows
Set @test= "January 04, 2021 11:16 AM"
Set @test1="1/4/2021 11:16:47 AM"

SET @Today= Now()
SET @SDL = SystemDateToLocalDate(@Today)
Set @Formatdate=Format(@Today, "d", "Date")

set @rows = LookupRows("TestDE","Createddate",@Today)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
]%%
CourseCount: %%=v(@rowCount)=%%
```

Comment: do the records in the DE have a time stamp?

Comment: @EazyE yes DE records have a time stamp

Comment: are you able to normalizae  the time stamp to 00:00:000

Comment: Sorry@EazyE, this format is customer request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMPscript will only do an exact comparison. We can't retrieve today records count from DE.
We need set up a SQL Query to put this into a separate DE. we can do something like just createdadate equal to today , or  between two specific times (e.g. 12:00AM and 11:59PM)
in query.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a quick test in my environment and by switching this line:

`set @rows = LookupRows("TestDE","Createddate",@Today)`

to

`set @rows = LookupRows("TestDE","Createddate",@Formatdate)`

it returned a course count.

Comment: Here Createdate field datatype is date, value is (3/4/2019 10:26:47 AM) dynamically loading. I tried @Formatdate also its not working